# Should I send a follow-up email to make sure my portfolio has been looked at?

Tags: interviewing, portfolio

I've sent my portfolio to an advertising agency 3 days ago. I'm sure they looked at it because it's hosted on my website and I could see their IP addresses visiting the website. One of these days was a national holiday, the others are normal business days.

Is it professionally acceptable to send a follow-up email to make sure my portfolio has been properly looked at?

Comment: What are you hoping to accomplish by sending another mail?

Comment: Because my mind goes like this "It's been three days already. Maybe a friendly reminder would help?"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Expressing interest in a position early in the resume collection process](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/11062/expressing-interest-in-a-position-early-in-the-resume-collection-process)

Comment: Them needing a reminder would imply extreme incompetence from their side. I'd imagine they can manage keeping track of candidates and reviewing them in sufficient detail.

Answer (score 5):

> I'm sure they looked at it because it's hosted on my website and I
>   could see their IP addresses visiting the website.
>
> Is it professionally acceptable to send a follow-up email to make sure
>   my portfolio has been properly looked at?

You know they looked at it.

So sending an email asking if they "properly" looked at it would be rather foolish.

Don't be a nag. Try to be more patient. It was only 3 days ago and one of the days wasn't even a work day.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it professionally acceptable to send a follow-up email to make sure my portfolio has been properly looked at?

It surely isn't unacceptable, but it may be *unnecessary*. It could even be seen as too insistent or desperate for your part if you send that email.

All recruitment processes take some time, how much greatly depending on every company. It is unlikely they forget to review applications they receive or obtain; if they don't contact you it is more likely that they thought you were not a good fit for the job.

However, I would not rush into any conclusions, and give them more time to respond before you can tell for sure (it has only been 3 days, wait *at least* a week).

In the meantime I suggest you keep your options open and try to look for other jobs you may like elsewhere.